# Configuration values are not updated after change the custom admin path in Magento 1.14.2.4

Tags: admin, adminhtml, configuration, ee-1.14.2.4

I have change the custom admin path as "backend" in Magento admin version 1.14.2.4. After that, I able to logged into the admin.

But I have  try to update the config values. it is not stored in databases.

Comment: have you done like this.. Goto System→Config→Admin→Admin Base Url→Use Custom Admin Path, set yes???

Comment: I have tried both local.xml and also in system configuration

Comment: you can check in database by  run this query 
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "%admin/url/%";